# Reporting an error while using data source with $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have created a factory to provide data to my app

```
myApp.factory('dataRepository', function ($resource) {
return {
   getApplicationErrors: function (applicationName) {

        return $resource('/api/DataSource/GetApplicationErrors').query();
    },
}
```

I have changed my data access from using $http, $q to use $resource into:

**old implementation**

```
 var deffered = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/api/DataSource/GetApplicationErrors').success(deffered.resolve).error(deffered.reject);

        return deffered.promise;
```

**new implementation**

```
  $scope.exceptions  = dataRepository.getApplicationErrors($routeParams.applicationName);
```

now in case that there is an error while fetching my data I want to display an error.

So when I had old implementation I had two callback to hook up to and now I am not sure how to implement it. My idea was:

```
myApp.controller("ErrorListController",
function ErrorListController($scope, dataRepository) {

dataRepository.getApplicationErrors('test')
.$promise
    .then(function (data) {
        $scope.exceptions = data;
    }, function(error) {
        $scope.errorMessage = 'Failed to load data from server';
    });
```

});

**Question**

What is correct way in hooking up to $resource success / fail?

**Possible answer**

Add call back functions for success and failure, but I do not consider this as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to consider is why are you changing to `$resource`?  The `$resource` service is supposed to provide a pseudo object-REST mapping.  So that you can get hold of objects and collections of objects, which you may wish to modify and save again.  If all you want is to have a service that retrieves a collection of errors then it may well be simpler to continue to use `$http`.

Second, the way to use `$resource` is to call it once inside your service factory function to create a concrete "typed/bound" resource object, which you then return as your service:

```
myApp.factory('dataRepository', function ($resource) {
  return {
    getApplicationErrors: $resource('/api/DataSource/GetApplicationErrors')
  };
}
```

In your controller you can inject this to get access to the resource methods. The first parameter of `query` is a `params` object, which basically gets passed straight through to `$http`. So you can do stuff there...

```
myApp.controller("ErrorListController",
    function ErrorListController($scope, dataRepository) {

  $scope.errors = dataRepository.getApplicationErrors.query({ params: { appName: 'test' });
};
```

This will immediately add an empty array to `$scope.errors` property.  When the response arrives, the resource will fill this array with the results.

If you want to catch errors then you can make use of the `$promise` property on the returned object.  This gives you access to the raw `$http` promise that is being used under the covers:

```
myApp.controller("ErrorListController",
    function ErrorListController($scope, dataRepository) {

  $scope.errors = dataRepository.getApplicationErrors.query({ params: { appName: 'test' });
  $scope.errors.$promise.then(success, error);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Http interceptors are probably your best bet for wrapping all response errors. It's essentially a way to wrap all of your http calls through angular. You're going to want to do something like this:

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyInterceptor');
})
.service('MyInterceptor', function($q, $injector) {
  return {
    responseError: function(error) {
      // Maybe you want to persist to database?
      $http = $injector.get('$http');
      $http.post('/log/my/error', error);

      //... Notify the user of the error here or add logic to dynamically propagate to the user
      alert("ERROR: " + error);

      // continue promise chain
      $q.reject(error);
    }
  };
});
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http). In the http interceptors section.